# how to create a git repo from that based on another open source repo

Tags: git

there is an existing open source project that been maintained by a group of developers, lets call him repo-A.

how one can use that project and develop his own features/plugins on the top of this base code?

the requirement to create different repo-B and whenever repo-A release a new version, merge repo-A into repo-B.

the merge is needed because there is a good possibility that the same core code will be changed once by my own project and the other by the open source developers (repo-A)

what is the best way of achieving that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the branch feature.

Suppose you `git clone repoA`, and want to merge repoB. Run the following command:

```
git remote add repob (giturl of repoB)    
git fetch repob
git merge repob/master
```

First, you add repoB as remote repo named repob. Then fetch all the code in repob. Finally merge repob/master branch to current repoA.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the permission from the owner/owners of the source code of repo-A

go to the folder where you want to put your repoB

```
git clone [protocol:]/path/to/repoA
```

then you work on your repoB (commit etc...)

As for the merge from repoA to repoB you use git pull but to do that you gonnna need to learn how to configure git.

Because:
1 - you want to clone repoA
2 - you want to set your own "distant" repository that way you will be able to push to your "distant" repository.
3 - you want to configure your local repoB to be able to pull from your "distant" repository
4 - you want to configure your local repoB to be able to pull from the repoA.

But if you don't need a "distant repository" all you need to do is clone repoA the first time, commit your work on your local repoB, and now and then

```
git pull [protocol:]/path/to/repoA
```

to get all the new things of repoA in your local repoB.

If you want an esay introduction to git with no deep shit : [IT'S HERE](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/)

[But you really should read the documentation](https://git-scm.com/doc)